# Not able to connect Socket.io in express

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, websocket, socket.io

I tried with a different solution to connect to the socket.io but I am not able to connect to it following is my code snippet.

app.js

> ```
> var express = require('express');
> var index = require('./routes/index');
> var users = require('./routes/users');
> var app = express();
> // view engine setup
> app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
> app.set('view engine', 'jade');
> app.use('/', index);
> app.use('/users', users);
> var http = require('http').Server(app);
> var io = require('socket.io')(http);
>
> io.on('connection', function(socket) {
>     console.log('Client connected.');
> });
>
>
> http.listen(3000, function(){
>   console.log('listening on *:3000');
> });
> ```

index.jade

```
extends layout

   script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
script.
  var socket = io();
```

Package.json after installing socket.io

```
"socket.io": "^2.0.3"
```

Please suggest me where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try with new key word, may be it will work

```
var app = new express();
```